# Hypermedia API for native clients (android, iOS)?

Tags: android, ios, api, rest, hypermedia

Do you think it is a good idea to expose hypermedia api (HATEOAS) for native clients (android, iOS)? What are the difficulties when the clients try to consume such an API?

I assume that the UI will be driven by the responses form the API.

I have zero experience with native clients and how they are built internally.

Answer (score 3):

Hypermedia seems made for mobile devices considering the limitations of data transfer due to speed, cost and availability.

This [post](http://www.jayway.com/2013/04/08/hypermedia-apis-with-mobile-clients/) addresses two of the concerns I had.

Perhaps someone else can speak to HATEOS libraries available for Native platforms.

HTH

Comment: 10x for the comment. This is a really nice post from Jan. My concerns are when building the UI for native dynamically and the latency which comes with this approach. Same addressed there. I hope more people share their experience here.